# Launch chrome with link and credentials through RUN

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, ftp

Is it possible to supply my FTP credentials directly through command when opening

it from RUN in my Windows 10?

[image]

Comment: Do you have to be using chrome? You can use Explorer to access ftp and save credentials, and have it saved as a shortcut

Comment: Is it possible with iexplore ftp://192.168.0.100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it appears you can, this worked for me:

```
chrome ftp://username:password@address
```

You can also use a Windows Explorer shortcut (which anyways is easier to use with an FTP site IMO) and check the box to save your credentials.

Comment: I might use it in a batch file later.